# Checking if a website exist with python3

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry if this is a duplicate i've been looking for answers for about an hour and can't seem to find any. Anyways, I have a text file full of urls and i want to check each one to see whether it exist or not. I need some help understanding the error message and if there are any ways to fix it or different methods i can use.

Here's my code

```
import requests

filepath = 'url.txt'  
with open(filepath) as fp:  
   url = fp.readline()
   count = 1
   while count != 677: #Runs through each line of my txt file
      print(url)
      request = requests.get(url) #Here is where im getting the error
      if request.status_code == 200:
          print('Web site exists')
      else:
        print('Web site does not exist')
      url = url.strip()
      count += 1
```

And this is the output

```
http://www.pastaia.co

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 9, in <module>
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: 
HTTPConnectionPool(host='www.pastaia.co%0a', port=80): Max retries exceeded 
with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection 
object at 0x7fca82769e10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] 
Name or service not known',))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll throw in ideas to get you started, whole careers are built around spidering :)  btw, http://www.pastaia.co seems to just be down.  And that's a big part of the trick, how to handle the unexpected when crawling the web.  Ready?  Here we go...

```
import requests

filepath = 'url.txt'
with open(filepath) as fp:
    for url in fp:
        print(url)
        try:
            request = requests.get(url) #Here is where im getting the error
            if request.status_code == 200:
                print('Web site exists')
        except:
            print('Web site does not exist')
```

- make it a `for` loop, you just want to loop the whole file right?
- do a `try` and `except` that way if it blows up for whatever reason of which there can be lots like, bad `DNS`, non `200` returned, perhaps it's a `.pdf` page, the web is the wild wild west.   This way the code won't crash and you can check the next site in the list and just record the error however you'd like.
- you can add other kinds of conditions in there too, perhaps the page needs to be a certain length?  And just because it's a `response code` `200` doesn't always mean the page is valid, just that the site returned `success`, but it's a good place to start.
- consider adding a `user-agent` to your request, you may want to mimic a browser, or perhaps have your program identify itself as `super bot 9000`
- if you want to get further into spidering and parsing of the text, look at using `beautifulsoup`: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Thanks! I got the error fixed but for some reason the request.get(url) does not seem to be working. I replaced url with http://www.google.com and it runs fine, but it doesn't work with url = fp.readline() when reading http://www.google.com. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: Never mind i fixed it using request = requests.get(url.strip())

Answer (score 1):

That website appears to not be serving web traffic: http://www.pastaia.co

Most likely, the requests module's `get()` function is attempting to connect multiple times to the url. It is eventually hitting its own internal retry limit at which point it throws a `ConnectionError` exception.

I would wrap this line in a try-catch block, to catch the error (thus signifying that the website doesn't exist:

```
try:
    request = requests.get(url)
    if request.status_code == 200:
        print('Web site exists')
    else:
        print("Website returned response code: {code}".format(code=request.status_code))
except ConnectionError:
    print('Web site does not exist')
    continue;
```